# How to Create an Embedded Hyperlink in a SAS Data Step

Tags: sas, datastep

The case is:
The target URL is for example "https://stackoverflow.com/".
I have a data set  with Ids. 
If I put   "https://stackoverflow.com/"+"ID" it is the final hyperlink, which leads to the final webpage.

How to create the list id Hyperlinks (data step) with URLs in which the name of every cell will be "ID" (after proc print), and when I click the hyperlink, it addresses me to 
"https://stackoverflow.com/3453456"  Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
%let url = https://stackoverflow.com/;

Data final_table;
set table_id;
Link='<A' || compress("HREF=""&url||">(ID) </A>;run;
```

but it goes with the error

** I did like Dompazz said, here is the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the question, can you add an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @JonathanLisic I added to  the main text

Comment: Hi Bobby, could I suggest to show code with Ctr+K marking rather then as an image? It is quicker and allows others to copy your code. Also, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the output location.  HTML, this works, putting a link in the table.

```
data test;
link = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>";
run;

ods html body="c:\temp\test.htm";
proc print data=test;
run;
ods html close;
```

But it fails in a PDF, just showing the text of the link.

```
ods pdf body="c:\temp\test.pdf";
proc print data=test;
run;
ods pdf close;
```

For PDFs, the code is `URL=...`.  So this generates a PDF where I can click on Google and open http://www.google.com

```
ods escapechar="^";
data test;
link = "^S={URL='http://www.google.com'}Google";
run;

ods pdf body="c:\temp\test2.pdf";
proc print data=test;
run;
ods pdf close;
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but how can i rename url  for examle instead of 'google'  to the observation of a variable

Comment: Use string concatenation functions to create a string with values from other variables.  i.e. `link="<a href='http://www.google.com'>" || VAR || "</a>";`

Comment: Anybody know if you can do something to make the link open in a new tab with the PDF output (similar to 'target="_blank"' if it were HTML output)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what error you have got, but you have some problems with your syntax when building your URL. See the working code below that generates one listing with URL to this question:

```
%LET url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/; 
data test;
ID = "34266798"; 
Url_Link = '<A '|| compress("HREF=&url")||ID||'> ID </A>'; 
RUN; 

PROC SQL;
    CREATE VIEW WORK.SORTTempTableSorted AS
        SELECT T.Url_Link
    FROM WORK.TEST as T
;QUIT;

PROC PRINT DATA=WORK.SORTTempTableSorted
    OBS="Row number"
    LABEL
    ;
    VAR Url_Link;
RUN;
```

Comment: Could you give more detail how it doesn't meet your expectation? When you click on "URL", it leads you to this quesion which is what you were trying to achieve in your code, right? Or do you need to see the full URL instead of "URL"?

Comment: I neet an URL named for ex. "The link" when you click it, browser opening an URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798

Comment: Huh, I was expecting that you have a default HTML ODS output open. My assumption was that your PROC PRINT already printing an HTML output.